# SQLite: populate table with count of matching rows from another

Tags: sqlite

I have a directory listing in a table called DATA (with a file extension field called DATAEXT) which I want to count in another table called STATS.

In the STATS table, I've already populated an STATSEXT column using;

```
INSERT INTO STATS (STATSEXT) SELECT DISTINCT DATAEXT FROM DATA;
```

I now want to write a query that goes through all the individual extensions listed in the STATS table, and counts the number of files with that extension in DATA, putting the result into a column called FILECOUNT in STATS.

I know I can use:

```
SELECT DATAEXT,count(*) FROM DATA GROUP BY DATAEXT
```

but it doesn't put the results into STATS.  Also, the solution needs to use the STATSEXT values in STATS as the basis of the lookup, rather than deriving it from the DATAEXT values, which is what the above does.

Any suggestions gratefully received. I've tried using a join based on a comparison of DATAEXT and STATSEXT, but it just counts the entire file listing (presumably as all the STATSEXT values are in the file listing somewhere).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `INSERT INTO STATS (STATSEXT) SELECT DISTINCT DATAEXT FROM DATA;` to populate STATS, you could populate and set the count all at once:

```
INSERT INTO STATS (STATSEXT, FILECOUNT)
SELECT DATAEXT,count(*) FROM DATA GROUP BY DATAEXT;
```

If you already have STATS populated and want to simply update the count, you could write a subquery update:

```
UPDATE STATS
SET FILECOUNT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM DATA WHERE DATAEXT = STATSEXT)
```

Comment: Great, thanks.  Yes, I thought there could be a way of populating all at once, but I've actually simplified the question a bit to ask it, and there's other reasons why I need to populate the table in stages.  Your second example works great though, so thank you.